# In manifest have a error how to solve this error

Tags: android-studio-2.3

```
Permission is only granted to system apps less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Permissions with the protection level signature, 
privileged or signatureOrSystem are only granted to system apps. If an 
app is a regular non-system app, it will never be able to use these 
permissions.  Issue id: ProtectedPermissions
```

How can I  solve this problem?

Comment: Hello koreanmartine, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you elaborate what you are trying to do? Currently, it only looks like you copied the error message from your IDE and ask us to figure it out. That's really hard without knowing what your main goal is ;)

Comment: in manifest add new permissions but have a red line that say haver error

Comment: Which permission exactly? It seems like you want to add a permission with a high protection level.